Python silently crashes after building scipy from source code, when `import _ufuncs`
I built scipy from source code according to this guide on Windows, the build was successful, The build was with command: python dev.py build --with-scipy-openblas.
Now I run Python and write the following code:
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/codeDom/scipy/build-install/Lib/site-packages")
from scipy.special import _ufuncs

Python just crashes without any error message.
I ran Python under Visual Studio's debugger and got an obscure error:

I tried using faulthandler and didn't get any useful information.
I also tried python -m pdb program.py, and nothing helped.
I also tried to check in ProcessMonitor if there is any missing DLL and I didn't find anything missing.
I think it's related to openblas but I'm not sure.
My question is how can I find out what the problem is? Why does Python crash without any error and how can you debug Python and find the error?

Which commit of SciPy are you installing? Is it a tagged version, or are you building from the main branch?

From the main branch with command: git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git

Are you looking to develop changes to SciPy, or are you looking for a working version of SciPy?

develop changes to SciPy

Hmm, not sure what else to try. Maybe you should ask about this on the issue tracker: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

We have windows build instructions in the docs, have you followed those? Following how the CI agents run the windows tests is also a good template to follow. Have you tried running python dev.py test?
